# axios post image base64 string return server 500 as response. Only happen on android devices, working fine on IOS

Tags: axios, react-native, react-native-ios

below is my code on post a base64 image string using axios. However, i only getting this fail when testing on android devices. somebody please help... Response: ['Request failed with status code 500'] is the response return from my server. IOS devices are able to upload base64 image without any issues.

```
const route = 'tools/uploadImage';
      axios
        .post(Config.apis_domain + route, {
          imageStr: values.profileImg,
          filename: 'abc123',
          container: 'jobseeker-profile',
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(`Upload Image failed : ${err}`));
```